# How to solve the error " missing required header GL/gl.h" while installing the Package mvoutlier in R?

Tags: r

I am trying to install the `package mvoutlier` but following error occurs during installation:

```
install.packages("mvoutlier")
configure: error: missing required header GL/gl.h 
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
* removing ‘/home/sam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library /2.15/rgl’
ERROR: dependency ‘rgl’ is not available for package ‘compositions’
* removing ‘/home/sam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/compositions’
ERROR: dependency ‘compositions’ is not available for package ‘mvoutlier’
* removing ‘/home/sam/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/mvoutlier’
```

After that I have install the rgl package successfully, then I tried to install the compositions package then the again same error occurs. Then I have again tried to install the mvoutlier package the same error occurs.

Can anyone let me know how I can resolve this problem. Thanking you in advance.

Comment: what errors showed up when installing compositions? After installing rgl the exact same errors appeared?

Comment: Do you get the same error with `install.packages("compositions" , dependencies = TRUE )`?

Comment: The error seems to be in rgl package, try to update it first: `update.packages(oldPkgs="rgl")`

Comment: @Hemmo I have installed updated version, though these error occurs

Comment: @SimonO101 I have also tried like this but the errors are same.

Comment: @EDi yes the same error appeared :(

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
configure: error: missing required header GL/gl.h
```

normally means you haven't installed the -dev version of a package, in this case GL.

On my system, GL/gl.h is owned by mesa-common-dev

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/include/GL/gl.h
mesa-common-dev: /usr/include/GL/gl.h
```

which would have been installed with `apt-get install mesa-common-dev` or via some GUI magic.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) I did the same and finally able to install the required package.

Comment: Hi I'm new to ubuntu environment. I encountered the same issue and I tried executing the above commands. But didn't work for me. Do I need administrative privileges to execute these commands?

Comment: For users of the RHEL family of distros `dnf install mesa*` does the trick.

Comment: Thank you Richard! this solved my problem in fedora :)

Answer (score 52):

I suspect you are running Ubuntu 12.04.I think you're going to find that this works for the `GL/gl.h` problem:

install these at the regular old terminal, ie pretend R doesn't exist for now:

```
libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev
```

You might get the following error later (in R) because of a tcl b****/gripe/complaint:

```
Error in structure(.External(.C_dotTcl, ...), class = "tclObj") : 
  [tcl] can't find package BWidget.
```

To fix this problem, if you have it:

```
sudo apt-get install bwidget
```

These are not R problems. They are OS problems!

Comment: The following worked for me (Linux Mint 17.2):

apt-get install libx11-dev
apt-get install mesa-common-dev
mesa-common-dev: /usr/include/GL/gl.h
dpkg -S /usr/include/GL/gl.h
apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev` solved this problem for me on Ubuntu 15.10. Thank you!

Comment: The accepted answer did not work for me (Ubuntu 16.04), but this one did the trick. Thanks.

Comment: for my debian I also add to install:  `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev` because after installing all the packages listed above I still had `fatal error: ft2build.h: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 41):

I ran into the same issue in between others on a Ubuntu based Linux distro (Linux Mint). Here I will share the worklog I'd done to fix it.

The full fix was:

`apt-get install  libx11-dev mesa-common-dev libglu1-mesa-dev`

### Worklog

The first error was related to missing devel libraries of X11:

`configure: error: X11 not found but required, configure aborted.`

I fixed it installing:

`apt-get install libx11-dev`

However, after fix the issue, I felt into a new one like this one:

`configure: error: missing required header GL/gl.h
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’`

I checked the library on the repository:

`# dpkg -S /usr/include/GL/gl.h
dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/include/GL/gl.h`

To fix this issue, install :

`apt-get install mesa-common-dev`

Then, I was prompt by a new error:

`configure: error: missing required header GL/glu.h`

To fix the issue, install the libglu1 devel libraries:

`apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev`

Answer (score 19):

On Ubuntu 16.04, I solved this problem (during `rgl` package installation) with `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev`

Comment: Worked for me as well on Mint 18.2 (based on Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: still working as only required line in ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Worked for me (ubuntu 20)

Answer (score 7):

the current fedora package manager will fail to find these libraries as shown.  Instead you need to do

```
    sudo dnf install mesa-libGL-devel mesa-libGLU-devel
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on the work breakdown by 3manuek, I figured only the libglu1-mesa-dev library was needed in ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

On, RHEL, `sudo yum install mesa-libGLU-devel` worked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered an equivalent problem when testing a package that required 'rgl' on Travis.  The problem is that the operating system lacks the necessary GL files on which the 'rgl' package draws.

A [thread at R-forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=6553&group_id=234&atid=946) offers the ingenious solution of running `apt-get install r-cran-rgl`, which will pull in any of the GL dependencies not already present on the operating system.  This seems simpler than second-guessing which specific dependency is missing, and it remains possible to install a more recent version of 'rgl' if required.