# Install all dependencies for quite a few packages in a view in an automatic way?

Tags: r, installation

I just installed the packages in time series view. There are some warnings at the end, which said some packages are installed with non-zero exit status. 
I looked at the earlier output, and found that the warnings are because some dependencies are "not available".

```
> install.views("TimeSeries")
...
ERROR: dependency ‘ks’ is not available for package ‘rugarch’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rugarch’
...
ERROR: dependencies ‘TSclust’, ‘longitudinalData’ are not available for package ‘TSdist’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/TSdist’
...
The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpBoB06G/downloaded_packages’
There were 34 warnings (use warnings() to see them)
> warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘gmp’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘proj4’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
4: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘rpanel’ had non-zero exit status
5: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘RGtk2’ had non-zero exit status
6: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘cairoDevice’ had non-zero exit status
7: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘KFKSDS’ had non-zero exit status
8: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘Rmpfr’ had non-zero exit status
9: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘RCurl’ had non-zero exit status
10: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘longitudinalData’ had non-zero exit status
11: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘kza’ had non-zero exit status
12: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘mar1s’ had non-zero exit status
13: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘Sim.DiffProc’ had non-zero exit status
14: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘stsm’ had non-zero exit status
15: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘Ecfun’ had non-zero exit status
16: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘httr’ had non-zero exit status
17: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘Bessel’ had non-zero exit status
18: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘ks’ had non-zero exit status
19: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘lubridate’ had non-zero exit status
20: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘Quandl’ had non-zero exit status
21: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘rdatamarket’ had non-zero exit status
22: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘Ecdat’ had non-zero exit status
23: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘FeedbackTS’ had non-zero exit status
24: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘nonlinearTseries’ had non-zero exit status
25: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘pdfetch’ had non-zero exit status
26: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘Rssa’ had non-zero exit status
27: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘TimeProjection’ had non-zero exit status
28: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘TSclust’ had non-zero exit status
29: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘tsoutliers’ had non-zero exit status
30: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘rugarch’ had non-zero exit status
31: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘TSdist’ had non-zero exit status
32: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘rmgarch’ had non-zero exit status
33: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘SDD’ had non-zero exit status
34: In install.packages(pkgs[[i]], repos = names(pkgs)[i],  ... :
  installation of package ‘x12GUI’ had non-zero exit status
```

1. Since there are not  just a few of them, is it possible to install all dependencies that haven't been installed in an automatic way?

   `warnings()` doesn't show  why the packages' installations failed, and the output of `install.views("TimeSeries")` is a  lot and  screens behind the current scrollable history.
2. I tried to run `install.views("TimeSeries", dependencies=TRUE)`, and the output is similar (i.e. some dependency packages are not available). I found the `dependencies` argument in the manpage for `install.packages()`, but didn't find it with the manpage of `install.views()`, and I still tried my luck to use it with `instal.views()`. Does the argument `dependencies` work with `install.views()`?
3. I also tried to install one dependency package individually, and
       still failed due to "configuration failed" for a dependency package
       which it further depends on:

   ```
   > install.packages("rgl", dependencies=TRUE)
   Installing package into ‘/home/t/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
   (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
   also installing the dependency ‘rmarkdown’

   trying URL 'http://watson.nci.nih.gov/cran_mirror/src/contrib/rmarkdown_0.5.1.tar.gz'
   Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 1164928 bytes (1.1 MB)
   ==================================================
   downloaded 1.1 MB

   trying URL 'http://watson.nci.nih.gov/cran_mirror/src/contrib/rgl_0.95.1201.tar.gz'
   Content type 'application/octet-stream' length 1922136 bytes (1.8 MB)
   ==================================================
   downloaded 1.8 MB

   * installing *source* package ‘rmarkdown’ ...
   ** package ‘rmarkdown’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
   ** R
   ** inst
   ** preparing package for lazy loading
   ** help
   *** installing help indices
   ** building package indices
   ** testing if installed package can be loaded
   * DONE (rmarkdown)
   * installing *source* package ‘rgl’ ...
   ** package ‘rgl’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
   checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
   checking whether the C compiler works... yes
   checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
   checking for suffix of executables... 
   checking whether we are cross compiling... no
   checking for suffix of object files... o
   checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
   checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
   checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
   checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
   checking for gcc... (cached) gcc -std=gnu99
   checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... (cached) yes
   checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... (cached) yes
   checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... (cached) none needed
   checking whether __attribute__((visibility())) is supported... yes
   checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -fvisibility... yes
   checking whether  accepts -fvisibility... no
   checking for libpng-config... yes
   configure: using libpng-config
   configure: using libpng dynamic linkage
   checking for X... libraries , headers 
   checking GL/gl.h usability... no
   checking GL/gl.h presence... no
   checking for GL/gl.h... no
   checking GL/glu.h usability... no
   checking GL/glu.h presence... no
   checking for GL/glu.h... no
   configure: error: missing required header GL/gl.h
   ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘rgl’
   * removing ‘/home/t/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/rgl’

   The downloaded source packages are in
       ‘/tmp/Rtmp5W5ULa/downloaded_packages’
   Warning message:
   In install.packages("rgl", dependencies = TRUE) :
     installation of package ‘rgl’ had non-zero exit status
   ```

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of ["installation of package 'FILE\_PATH' had non-zero exit status" in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27893230/installation-of-package-file-path-had-non-zero-exit-status-in-r)

Comment: Thanks. I looked at the earlier output, and found that the warnings are because some dependencies are not installed yet.  Since there are not  just a few of them, how shall I do to fix them? (Note that the reasons in your linked post seem not the same as here)

Comment: Do you need to install an appropriate [library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15292905/how-to-solve-the-error-missing-required-header-gl-gl-h-while-installing-the-p#15293440) first? You need `GL/gl.h` which might be the reason why the dependencies could not be installed.

Comment: @martin: Thanks. I added `dependencies=TRUE` in `install.packages("rgl", dependencies=TRUE)`, and seems like still have the same error. Doesn't `dependencies=TRUE` install dependencies automatically?

Comment: This is a system library issue, not an R issue.

Answer (score 3):

When looking at the output, you see:

```
checking for X... libraries , headers 
checking GL/gl.h usability... no
checking GL/gl.h presence... no
checking for GL/gl.h... no
checking GL/glu.h usability... no
checking GL/glu.h presence... no
checking for GL/glu.h... no
configure: error: missing required header GL/gl.h
```

which means that your system does not have the required headers in order to compile `rgl`. You need to install those headers. On my Ubuntu 14.04 system, I would have to use

```
sudo apt-get install mesa-common-dev
```

after which the compilation/configuration should proceed a little further.

In contrast, `dependencies=true` only installs the R dependencies and not those belonging to the operating system.

Comment: Thanks. That solved the problem of installing package "rgl". Back to original question, when I installed the packages in the view `TimeSeries`, is there some way to solve the problem for all the packages in the view? Also `warnings()` doesn't show  why the packages' installations failed, and the output of `install.views("TimeSeries")` is a  lot and  screens behind the current scrollable history.

Comment: Can we save the output of `install.views()` (too many screens) to a file or something, so we can examine the output if there are warnings?

Comment: If you use gnome-terminal, you could set the scrollback buffer to a larger value: `Edit -> profile settings -> scrolling` to unlimited (free translation, might not be 100% accurate).

Comment: Thanks. Still there are other C libraries to be installed. The output of `install.views()` doesn't collect the detail enough info at the end, and I have to look at all the long output (some are already outside the srollable range, so search  in gnome terminal won't find them?)

Answer (score 2):

if you use a debian based linux distro, Install gtk2 by typing

```
sudo apt install libgtk2.0-dev
```

and try again in R.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I can't just comment...If I could of, it would of been "Run man R and see the Redirection section in the free Advanced Bash Scripting Guide."

Try:

1. `man R`
2. Download or view a copy of [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/) (or [abs-guide.pdf](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/abs-guide.pdf)), and read section about Redirection.

   ```
   &>filename
   # Redirect both stdout and stderr to file "filename."
   # This operator is now functional, as of Bash 4, final release.
   ```
3. Put your `install.views("TimeSeries")` into an R script file.
4. On the command line, run:

   R [your options here] CMD BATCH "~/path/to/r/script/file.r" &>filename

I don't have any desire to install all the TimeSeries packages so I have not tested anything I have written.